# ¿cómo puedo retornar el resultado de un StoredProcedure Mediante ado.net?

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, controller, ado.net

Estoy intentado retornar el resultado de un StoredProcedure en un controlador de MVC .net Iaction result con Ado.net, lo he intentado realizar mediante un ejemplo pero no logro retornar el resultado del procedimiento almacenado

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LlamdoSp(string Fecha, string Cntr, string bl)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            //using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var lista = new List<string>();
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Liquidacion_Demoras_CMA", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Fecha);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cntr", Cntr);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bl", bl);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    lista.Add(
                        dr
                    ) ;
                }
                return Json(lista);
            }
```

Comment: ¿Podrias indicar que devuelve el procedimeinto almacenado "SP_Liquidacion_Demoras_CMA"? Porque veo que queires devuelver un listado de string, pero seguramente devuelve mas campos? o solo uno del tipo cadena? Asi podremos ayudarte como se arma o usa [ExecuteReader (que puedes leer algo aqui)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: El procedimiento almacenado devuelve un string, lo del listado es por el ejmplo

Answer (score 1):

Para cuando ejecutas [ExecuteReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) que devuelve una instancia de un "lector"/"reader", en tu caso si estas contra una DB SQL Server sería [SqlDataReader Clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) que es por decirlo de una forma es un punturo a una respuesta de la DB de solo lectura secuencial 8por eso dice "solo avance" en la documentacion

> **SqlDataReader** : Ofrece una manera de leer un flujo de filas de solo avance desde una base de datos de SQL Server.

Por esta razon lo primero que se debe realizar luego de ejecutar es preguntar si se puede leer, veras en la documentacion que llama al metodo [Read()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) del DataReader

En tu caso seria

```
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        lista.Add(dr[0]) ;
    }

 return Json(lista);
```

REcomendaciones a tener encuenta, o dale una mirada

- Cuando llamas a *dr[indice]* esto devuelve un object
- Puedes utilizar (si es un string) [GetString(indice)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) hay otros tipos de metodos que te ayudan a obtener un tipo especifico.
- Si en la consulta puede venir "null" entonces podrias llamar a [IsDBNull(indice)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [ExecuteReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)
- [SqlDataReader Clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)
- [SqlDataReader.GetString(indice)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía